# Tensorflow memory leak with Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a simple Recurrent Neural Network model by using tensorflow on Mac OS X. It is just a toy model and size of input data doesn't exceed 3MB so it should not consume much of memory. However, when I run model, the memory usage significantly increases every training batch and goes above 10GB. It was for only two iterations. I couldn't run it more.

Here's the whole code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from pympler import summary

class RNN():
    """The RNN model."""
    #@profile
    def inference(self):
        """calculate outputs and loss for a single batch"""
        total_loss = 0.0
        outputs = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            state = self.init_state
            outputs.append([])
            loss = 0.0
            for j in range(self.num_steps):
                state, output = self.next_state(self.x[i,j,:],state)
                outputs[i].append(output)
                loss += tf.square(self.y[i,j,:]-output)
            total_loss+=loss
        return outputs, total_loss / (self.batch_size*self.num_steps)

    def __init__(self, is_training, config):
        self.sess = sess = tf.Session()

        self.prev_see = prev_see = config.prev_see
        self.num_steps = num_steps = config.num_steps
        #maybe "self.num_hidden =" part could be removed
        self.num_hidden = num_hidden = config.num_hidden
        self.batch_size = config.batch_size
        self.epoch = config.epoch
        self.learning_rate = config.learning_rate
        self.summaries_dir = config.summaries_dir

        with tf.name_scope('placeholders'):
            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,num_steps,config.prev_see],
                                    name='input-x')
            self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,num_steps,1],name='input-y')
            default_init_state = tf.zeros([num_hidden])
            self.init_state = tf.placeholder_with_default(default_init_state,[num_hidden],
                                                     name='state_placeholder')

        def weight_variable(self,shape):
            """Create a weight variable with appropriate initialization."""
            initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.1)
            return tf.Variable(initial)

        def bias_variable(self,shape):
            """Create a bias variable with appropriate initialization."""
            initial = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
            return tf.Variable(initial)

        def variable_summaries(self,var,name):
            """Attach a lot of summaries to a Tensor."""
            with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
                mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
                tf.scalar_summary('mean/'+name,mean)
                with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
                    stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(var-mean)))
                tf.scalar_summary('stddev/'+name,stddev)
                tf.scalar_summary('max/'+name, tf.reduce_max(var))
                tf.scalar_summary('min/'+name, tf.reduce_min(var))
                tf.histogram_summary(name, var)

        #declare weight variables as property
        layer_name = 'rnn_layer'
        with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
            with tf.name_scope('U'):
                self.U = U = weight_variable(self,[prev_see,num_hidden])
                variable_summaries(self,U,layer_name+'/U')
            with tf.name_scope('W'):
                self.W = W = weight_variable(self,[num_hidden,num_hidden])
                variable_summaries(self,W,layer_name+'/W')
            with tf.name_scope('b_W'):
                self.b_W = b_W = bias_variable(self,[num_hidden])
                variable_summaries(self,b_W,layer_name+'/b_W')
            with tf.name_scope('V'):
                self.V = V = weight_variable(self,[num_hidden,1])
                variable_summaries(self,V,layer_name+'/V')
            with tf.name_scope('b_V'):
                self.b_V = b_V = bias_variable(self,[1])
                variable_summaries(self,b_V,layer_name+'/b_V')
        self.merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
        self.train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(config.summaries_dir,sess.graph)
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run(session=sess)
        _,self.loss = self.inference()


    def next_state(self,x,s_prev):
        """calculate next state and output"""
        x = tf.reshape(x,[1,-1])
        s_prev = tf.reshape(s_prev,[1,-1])        
        s_next = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x,self.U)+tf.matmul(s_prev,self.W)+self.b_W)
        output = tf.matmul(s_next,self.V)+self.b_V
        return s_next, output

    #@profile
    def batch_train(self,feed_dict):
        """train the network for a single batch"""
        loss = self.loss
        train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(loss)
        summary,loss_value, _ = self.sess.run([self.merged,loss, train_step],feed_dict=feed_dict)
        #self.train_writer.add_summary(summary)
        print(loss_value)


class TrainConfig():
    """Train Config.""" 
    total_steps = 245
    test_ratio = 0.3
    prev_see = 100
    num_steps = int(round((total_steps-prev_see)*(1-test_ratio)))
    num_hidden = 10
    batch_size = 5
    epoch = 3
    learning_rate = 0.1
    summaries_dir = '/Users/Kyungsu/StockPrediction/log'

class DebugConfig():
    """For debugging memory leak."""
    total_steps = 100
    test_ratio = 0.3
    prev_see = 100
    num_steps = 10
    num_hidden = 10
    batch_size = 5 
    epoch = 2 
    learning_rate = 0.1
    summaries_dir = '/Users/Kyungsu/StockPrediction/log'

#@profile
def run_epoch(m,x_data,y_data):
    num_batch = ((len(x_data)-1) // m.batch_size)+1 
    #num_batch = 100
    for i in range(num_batch):
        x_batch = x_data[i*m.batch_size:(i+1)*m.batch_size,:,:]
        y_batch = y_data[i*m.batch_size:(i+1)*m.batch_size,:,:]
        feed_dict = {m.x:x_batch,m.y:y_batch}
        print("%dth/%dbatches"%(i+1,num_batch))
        m.batch_train(feed_dict)

def process_data(data,config):
    data_size = len(data)
    prev_see = config.prev_see
    num_steps = config.num_steps
    x = np.zeros((data_size,num_steps,prev_see))
    y = np.zeros((data_size,num_steps,1))
    for i in range(data_size):
        for j in range(num_steps-prev_see):
            x[i,j,:] = data[i,i:i+prev_see]
            y[i,j,0] = data[i,i+prev_see]
    return x,y

#@profile
def main():
    train_config = TrainConfig()
    debug_config = DebugConfig()
    data = np.load('processed_data.npy')
    x,y = process_data(data,train_config)
    rnn_model = RNN(True,train_config)

    #training phase
    for i in range(rnn_model.epoch):
        print("%dth epoch"%(i+1))
        run_epoch(rnn_model,x,y)

main()
```

And following is the result of [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).
Weird thing is, most of memory is allocated in *for loop*. (See line 163,135) I guess it means memory is leaking.

```
  Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    11   53.062 MiB    0.000 MiB       @profile
    12                                 def __init__(self, is_training, config):
    13   53.875 MiB    0.812 MiB           self.sess = sess = tf.Session()
    14                                     
    15   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.prev_see = prev_see = config.prev_see
    16   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.num_steps = num_steps = config.num_steps
    17                                     #maybe "self.num_hidden =" part could be removed
    18   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.num_hidden = num_hidden = config.num_hidden
    19   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.batch_size = config.batch_size
    20   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.epoch = config.epoch
    21   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.learning_rate = config.learning_rate
    22   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.summaries_dir = config.summaries_dir
    23                             
    24   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB           with tf.name_scope('input'):
    25   53.875 MiB    0.000 MiB               self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,num_steps,config.prev_see],
    26   53.957 MiB    0.082 MiB                                       name='input-x')
    27   53.973 MiB    0.016 MiB               self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,num_steps,1],name='input-y')
    28                                     
    29   55.316 MiB    1.344 MiB           def weight_variable(self,shape):
    30                                         """Create a weight variable with appropriate initialization."""
    31   55.371 MiB    0.055 MiB               initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.1)
    32   55.414 MiB    0.043 MiB               return tf.Variable(initial)
    33                             
    34   55.707 MiB    0.293 MiB           def bias_variable(self,shape):
    35                                         """Create a bias variable with appropriate initialization."""
    36   55.727 MiB    0.020 MiB               initial = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    37   55.754 MiB    0.027 MiB               return tf.Variable(initial)
    38                                     
    39   55.754 MiB    0.000 MiB           def variable_summaries(self,var,name):
    40                                         """Attach a lot of summaries to a Tensor."""
    41   55.754 MiB    0.000 MiB               with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
    42   55.801 MiB    0.047 MiB                   mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
    43   55.824 MiB    0.023 MiB                   tf.scalar_summary('mean/'+name,mean)
    44   55.824 MiB    0.000 MiB                   with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
    45   55.883 MiB    0.059 MiB                       stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(var-mean)))
    46   55.906 MiB    0.023 MiB                   tf.scalar_summary('stddev/'+name,stddev)
    47   55.969 MiB    0.062 MiB                   tf.scalar_summary('max/'+name, tf.reduce_max(var))
    48   56.027 MiB    0.059 MiB                   tf.scalar_summary('min/'+name, tf.reduce_min(var))
    49   56.055 MiB    0.027 MiB                   tf.histogram_summary(name, var)
    50                                     
    51                                     #declare weight variables as property
    52   53.973 MiB   -2.082 MiB           layer_name = 'rnn_layer'
    53   53.973 MiB    0.000 MiB           with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    54   53.973 MiB    0.000 MiB               with tf.name_scope('U'):
    55   54.230 MiB    0.258 MiB                   self.U = U = weight_variable(self,[prev_see,num_hidden])
    56   54.598 MiB    0.367 MiB                   variable_summaries(self,U,layer_name+'/U')
    57   54.598 MiB    0.000 MiB               with tf.name_scope('W'):
    58   54.691 MiB    0.094 MiB                   self.W = W = weight_variable(self,[num_hidden,num_hidden])
    59   54.961 MiB    0.270 MiB                   variable_summaries(self,W,layer_name+'/W')
    60   54.961 MiB    0.000 MiB               with tf.name_scope('b_W'):
    61   55.012 MiB    0.051 MiB                   self.b_W = b_W = bias_variable(self,[num_hidden])
    62   55.316 MiB    0.305 MiB                   variable_summaries(self,b_W,layer_name+'/b_W')
    63   55.316 MiB    0.000 MiB               with tf.name_scope('V'):
    64   55.414 MiB    0.098 MiB                   self.V = V = weight_variable(self,[num_hidden,1])
    65   55.707 MiB    0.293 MiB                   variable_summaries(self,V,layer_name+'/V')
    66   55.707 MiB    0.000 MiB               with tf.name_scope('b_V'):
    67   55.754 MiB    0.047 MiB                   self.b_V = b_V = bias_variable(self,[1])
    68   56.055 MiB    0.301 MiB                   variable_summaries(self,b_V,layer_name+'/b_V')
    69   56.055 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    70   60.348 MiB    4.293 MiB           self.train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(config.summaries_dir,sess.graph)
    71   62.496 MiB    2.148 MiB           tf.initialize_all_variables().run(session=sess)


Filename: rnn.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    82 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB       @profile
    83                                 def inference(self):
    84                                     """calculate outputs and loss for a single batch"""
    85 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB           total_loss = 0.0
    86 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB           outputs = []
    87 3022.352 MiB    9.016 MiB           for i in range(self.batch_size):
    88 3020.441 MiB   -1.910 MiB               state = tf.zeros([self.num_hidden])
    89 3020.441 MiB    0.000 MiB               outputs.append([])
    90 3020.441 MiB    0.000 MiB               loss = 0.0
    91 3022.348 MiB    1.906 MiB               for j in range(self.num_steps):
    92 3022.285 MiB   -0.062 MiB                   state, output = self.next_state(self.x[i,j,:],state)
    93 3022.285 MiB    0.000 MiB                   outputs[i].append(output)
    94 3022.348 MiB    0.062 MiB                   loss += tf.square(self.y[i,j,:]-output)
    95 3022.352 MiB    0.004 MiB               total_loss+=loss
    96 3022.371 MiB    0.020 MiB           return outputs, total_loss / (self.batch_size*self.num_steps)


Filename: rnn.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    97 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB       @profile
    98                                 def batch_train(self,feed_dict):
    99                                     """train the network for a single batch"""
   100 3022.371 MiB    9.035 MiB           _, loss = self.inference()
   101 3051.781 MiB   29.410 MiB           train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(loss)
   102 3149.891 MiB   98.109 MiB           summary,loss_value, _ = self.sess.run([self.merged,loss, train_step],feed_dict=feed_dict)
   103                                     #self.train_writer.add_summary(summary)
   104 3149.891 MiB    0.000 MiB           print(loss_value)


Filename: rnn.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   131 1582.758 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
   132                             def run_epoch(m,x_data,y_data):
   133 1582.758 MiB    0.000 MiB       num_batch = ((len(x_data)-1) // m.batch_size)+1 
   134                                 #num_batch = 100
   135 3149.895 MiB 1567.137 MiB       for i in range(num_batch):
   136 3013.336 MiB -136.559 MiB           x_batch = x_data[i*m.batch_size:(i+1)*m.batch_size,:,:]
   137 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB           y_batch = y_data[i*m.batch_size:(i+1)*m.batch_size,:,:]
   138 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB           feed_dict = {m.x:x_batch,m.y:y_batch}
   139 3013.336 MiB    0.000 MiB           print("%dth/%dbatches"%(i+1,num_batch))
   140 3149.891 MiB  136.555 MiB           m.batch_train(feed_dict)


Filename: rnn.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   154   52.914 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
   155                             def main():
   156   52.914 MiB    0.000 MiB       train_config = TrainConfig()
   157   52.914 MiB    0.000 MiB       debug_config = DebugConfig()
   158   53.059 MiB    0.145 MiB       data = np.load('processed_data.npy')
   159   53.062 MiB    0.004 MiB       x,y = process_data(data,debug_config)
   160   62.496 MiB    9.434 MiB       rnn_model = RNN(True,debug_config)
   161                             
   162                                 #training phase
   163 3149.898 MiB 3087.402 MiB       for i in range(rnn_model.epoch):
   164 1582.758 MiB -1567.141 MiB           print("%dth epoch"%(i+1))
   165 3149.898 MiB 1567.141 MiB           run_epoch(rnn_model,x,y)
```

This problem was not occured when I tried simple [MNIST model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) from tensorflow tutorial. So it should be related with RNN model.
Also, I could reproduce this problem on Ubuntu 14.04, so I don't think this problem is caused by OS X things.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that this line

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

occurs in your batch_train function, so on every iteration, a **new** GradientDescentOptimizer is created. Try moving this to your model's init function just after you define the loss and refer to self.train_step in your batch_train function instead.